# Catkin can't find move_base

Tags: navigation, catkin, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to rebuild a package I made in fuerte in groovy. Back in fuerte it depended on move_base and move_base_msgs. When I try to make it using catkin in groovy I get the following:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'autonomous_navigation'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(autonomous_navigation)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 
(find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package move_base.

  Set move_base_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for move_base. The file will have one of the following names:

    move_baseConfig.cmake
    move_base-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  autonomouse_navigation/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71 
(find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package move_base_msgs.

  Set move_base_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for move_base_msgs. The file will have one of the following names:

    move_base_msgsConfig.cmake
    move_base_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  autonomouse_navigation/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

I get a similar error trying to follow the Simple Sending Goals tutorial under navigation. The error is just for move_base_msgs since move_base isn't a dependency of the package.

Did the move_base package change? What do I need to do to be able to use the move_base for setting up navigational goals?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57444/catkin-can%27t-find-move_base/) by [mculp42](https://answers.ros.org/users/3996/mculp42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

move_base is part of the navigation stack, which is not catkinized. A catkin-based package cannot depend on a rosbuild based package, you should probably stick with rosbuild for now, or catkinize navigation and build from source.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4